# Ruby separating an array of strings by checking whether or not the object inherits from a certain class

Tags: ruby

- I have an array of strings that I read from a file  `x`
- I have an empty array `y`
- Some string objects are integers
- How do I separate the integers from the strings, **specifically by using a call `to_a?`**

Right now i'm trying

```
x.each do |s|
  if s.to_i.is_a?(Integer)
   y << s
 end
end
```

but this just converts everything to an integer and stuffs it in `y`, is there a way to see if an object is truly from the Integer class?

**Edit add sample input/output**

```
x = [ "This", "is", "a", "random", "amalgamation", "of", "text", "and", "a",
      "bunch", "of", "numbers", "111113087403957304739703975", "how", "can", "I",
      "read", "this", "in." ]

y = [ 111113087403957304739703975 ]
```

Comment: Can you write a sample of the input you have and a sample of the output you want

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.0.0 I just added a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x.each do |s|
    begin
      Integer(s)
    rescue ArgumentError
    else
      y << s
    end
end
```

If applied on a string that doesn't parse as an integer, `Integer()` raises an `ArgumentError`. You can use this to find integer strings.

Comment: I think you have a stray `else` in there.

Comment: @Jordan, the else branch of a begin/rescue block will execute when no exception is found

Comment: @Jordan It's part of the `begin rescue end`. I only learned that it exists just recently (it's in Python too), and I kind of like how it allows me to separate the potentially exception raising part of my begin clause (`Integer(s)`) from the rest (`y<<s`).

Comment: So I understand this correctly, this iterates through the array and rescues all exceptions to Integer(s) and appends the rest to y?

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend against using exceptions for flow control. It's not a very good pattern. Read more: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Answer (score 4):

```
x = [ "This", "is", "a", "random", "amalgamation", "of", "text", "and", "a",
      "bunch", "of", "numbers", "111113087403957304739703975", "how", "can", "I",
      "read", "this", "in." ]

y = [ 111113087403957304739703975 ]

def extract_integers(array)
  array.select { |v| v.match(/\A\d+\z/) }.map(&:to_i)
  # or (simpler, as suggested by @theTinMan)
  array.reject { |v| v[/\D/] }.map(&:to_i)
end

p extract_integers(x)      #=> [111113087403957304739703975]
p extract_integers(x) == y #=> true
```

Comment: You can reverse the test and make it a bit more simple: `reject { |v| v[/\D/] }`

Answer (score 3):

`s.match(/^\d+$/)` will match a string containing only numbers, so you can use this to test your strings against

Answer (score 3):

You might use [Enumerable#grep](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
arr = %w[9 cats on 33 hot tin roofs] 
   #=> ["9", "cats", "on", "33", "hot", "tin", "roofs"]

arr.grep /^\d+$/
  #=> ["9", "33"]
arr.grep(/^\d+$/).map(&:to_i)
  #=> [9, 33]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always interesting, and useful to run benchmarks:

```
require 'fruity'

x = [ "This", "is", "a", "random", "amalgamation", "of", "text", "and", "a",
  "bunch", "of", "numbers", "111113087403957304739703975", "how", "can", "I",
  "read", "this", "in." ]

def extract_integers(array)
  array.select { |v| v.match(/\A\d+\z/) }.map(&:to_i)
end

def extract_integers_reject(array)
  array.reject { |v| v[/\D/] }.map(&:to_i)
end


compare do
  use_exception {
    y = []
    x.each do |s|
      begin
        Integer(s)
      rescue ArgumentError
      else
        y << s.to_i
      end
    end
    y
  }

  use_extract_integers {
    extract_integers(x)
  }

  use_extract_integers_reject {
    extract_integers_reject(x)
  }
end
```

Running that results in the following on my machine:

```
Running each test 256 times. Test will take about 1 second.
use_extract_integers_reject is faster than use_extract_integers by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
use_extract_integers is faster than use_exception by 6x ± 0.1
```

Note, `y << s` was changed to `y << s.to_i` to make the outputs all match.

---

I'd probably simplify the code using the ArgumentError rescue like this:

```
x.each do |s|
  begin
    y << Integer(s)
  rescue ArgumentError
  end
end
```